# Is it possible to deploy an Angular app in many languages to AWS Amplify?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, internationalization, aws-amplify

I want to have an Angular app translated into many languages for internationalization (i18n). Angular has a built-in i18n module that allows you to build your app into specific locales and languages. But this approach requires you to build a new app for each language. So for English, I must build an app, for Chinese a separate app and so on for each language.

How I was going to approach it is, for each language that isn't English have a folder with the language code (en, cn, ru, fr, de) containing the Angular single-page app.

- domain.com -> English
- domain.com/cn -> Chinese
- domain.com/ru -> Russian
- domain.com/fr -> French
- domain.com/de -> German

Is it possible to achieve this with AWS Amplify? I think AWS Amplify has some routing setup that forces the server to always serve the index.html file in the Angular app in the root folder, but if I was going to do the approach I mentioned above with the folder for each language, is there some additional configuration required on the server and is this even possible with AWS Amplify?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are also looking for a answer to this question. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Hi I ended up going with Firebase Hosting and found it much easier to achieve this.